# Python `requests` cookies not loading all cookies into subdomain from main domain

Tags: python, python-requests, reverse-engineering

I'm reverse engineering a company's internal API to make a python client. In order to use it, the company requires three cookies — one indicating the premium key (on premium.website.com), the other reflecting the refresh and access token (on website.com), which are required for access. I looked at my browser and extracted the tokens from my cookies. However, I'm unable to get API access. Minimum viable example:

```
import requests

premium_session: requests.Session = requests.Session()
premium_session.cookies.set("premium_key", credentials["premium_key"], domain = "premium.website.com")
premium_session.cookies.set("access_token", credentials["access_token"], domain = ".website.com")
premium_session.cookies.set("refresh_token", credentials["refresh_token"], domain = ".website.com")

premium_endpoint = premium_session.get("https://premium.website.com/api/v1/endpoint")
print(premium_endpoint.cookies)
```

When I view the `cookies` method, I only see the cookie for `premium.website.com`, not `website.com` which is necessary to access the data.

I've tried messing around with the cookie domain, to no avail. I even tried making a request to `website.com` to see if that would fix the problem — it does not. When I view the API Endpoints in my browser, it works perfectly.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright wow, as I was working on this I miraculously discovered the fix — I simply needed to change the domain of the `.website.com` cookies to `premium.website.com` and it worked. Hopefully this helps someone someday!